# How to bind touch coordinates to the image

Tags: android

I am working on a Compass type Android application, where I would have an image of a Compass, with letters indicating various directions ('N' for North, 'E' for East and so on). The user could press any of the letters and get some info about a given direction. I am looking for a way how to bind the touch coordinates to the image, i.e. if a user press a letter 'N' they would always get similar coordinates irrelevant to which direction handset is facing. Below is the code I am using now.

```
@Override
  public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater,
                           ViewGroup container,
                           Bundle savedInstanceState) {
   View v=inflater.inflate(R.layout.compass_fragment, container, false);

   compassView = (CompassView) v.findViewById(R.id.compass_view);



   compassView.setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener() {
       @Override
       public boolean onTouch(View view, MotionEvent motion) {

           Log.i(TAG, "In onTouch");

           // Get the action that was done on this touch event
           switch (motion.getAction())
           {

                case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
                {
                    return true;
                }

               case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
               {
                   float x = motion.getX();
                   float y = motion.getY();

                   Log.i(TAG, "ACTION UP x = " + x + " y = " + y);
                   break;
               }
           }
           // if you return false, these actions will not be recorded
           return true;
       }
   });


    mSensorManager = (SensorManager)getActivity().getSystemService(Context.SENSOR_SERVICE);
    accelerometer = mSensorManager.getDefaultSensor(Sensor.TYPE_ACCELEROMETER);
    magnetometer = mSensorManager.getDefaultSensor(Sensor.TYPE_MAGNETIC_FIELD);

    return(v);
  }
```

Comment: So you know how to rotate the image and you don't know how to bind it with touch?

Comment: Gina, no I don't know, I guess otherwise I wouldn't ask the question. I am new to Android, still learning how it all works together. Looks like it's obvious to you how to do it, I would appreciate to get some pointers from you. Thank you.

Comment: Then find out how to rotate a image. For the "N" or "E" make it a object like Button/ImageButton so you don't need to know the coordinates.

Comment: Yes, I was thinking about using Button/ImageButton, but I wondered if there something similar to 'locationInView' in iOS which returns the coordinates of the touch in the local coordinate system of the view (to which the gesture recognizer is attached).

Answer (score 0):

I worked it out the answer to my question. It works the way I wanted, without using the buttons. I attached below the code, hope it might be useful for someone else.

To get the touched direction on the compass I calculate the offset angle between the current compass bearing (degrees variable which updated by setDegrees method called from another class) and the angle of the touch location in relation to the Y axis.

```
public class CompassView extends ImageView {
    private float degrees=0;
    private String touchDirection;

    public CompassView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
        int height = this.getHeight();
        int width = this.getWidth();

        canvas.rotate(360-degrees, width/2, height/2);
        super.onDraw(canvas);
    }

    public void setDegrees(float degrees) {
        this.degrees = degrees;
        this.invalidate();
    }

    @Override
      public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {

        switch (event.getAction()) {
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
                return true;
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
                break;
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
                float eventX = event.getX();
                float eventY = event.getY();

                touchDirection = getTouchDirection(eventX, eventY);

                Context context = getContext();
                Intent intent = new Intent(context, CompassDirectionInfo.class);
                Bundle bundle = new Bundle();   
                bundle.putString("DIRECTION", touchDirection);
                intent.putExtras(bundle); 
                context.startActivity(intent);
                break;
            default:
                return false;
        }
        return true;
      }

    private String getTouchDirection (float eventX, float eventY) {

        String direction = "";

        float centreX = getWidth()/2, centreY = getHeight()/2;
        float tx = (float) (eventX - centreX), ty = (float) (eventY - centreY);
        float radius = (float) Math.sqrt(tx*tx + ty*ty);

        float offsetX = 0, offsetY = radius, adjEventX = eventX - centreX, adjEventY = centreY - eventY;

        double cosaU = ((offsetX * adjEventX) + (offsetY * adjEventY));
        double cosaD = ( Math.sqrt((offsetX * offsetX) + (offsetY * offsetY)) * Math.sqrt((adjEventX * adjEventX) + (adjEventY * adjEventY)));
        double cosa = cosaU / cosaD;

        double degr = ( Math.acos(cosa) * (180 / Math.PI));

        if (adjEventX < 0)
            degr = 360 - degr;

        float offsetDegrees = (float) (degrees + degr);

        if (offsetDegrees > 360)
            offsetDegrees = offsetDegrees - 360;

         if (offsetDegrees < 22.5 || offsetDegrees > 336.5)
             direction = "NORTH";
         else if (offsetDegrees > 22.5 && offsetDegrees < 67.5)
             direction = "NORTHEAST";
         else if (offsetDegrees > 67.5 && offsetDegrees < 112.5)
             direction = "EAST";
         else if (offsetDegrees > 112.5 && offsetDegrees < 156.5)
             direction = "SOUTHEAST";
         else if (offsetDegrees > 156.5 && offsetDegrees < 201.5)
             direction = "SOUTH";
         else if (offsetDegrees > 201.5 && offsetDegrees < 246.5)
             direction = "SOUTHWEST";
         else if (offsetDegrees > 246.5 && offsetDegrees < 291.5)
             direction = "WEST";
         else if (offsetDegrees > 291.5 && offsetDegrees < 336.5)
             direction = "NORTHWEST";

         return direction;
    }
}
```